# Таймеры и рекурсия в javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте. Написал код, который по таймеру применяет стили к выбранным элементам. Но столкнулся с глупой проблемой, не могу сделать что бы он работал цикл за циклом, бесконечно. Вложить функцию в массив - подвешивает браузер. Рекурсивно вызвать не получается у меня, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать? Что бы переменные по которым идут итерации вернулись к исходному значению и скрипт пошел по новой. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

```
window.elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(elems);
window.i = 22;
window.j = 22;
function clear (){
  clearInterval(timer);
}
function timer () { 
window.timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (i > 4) {
      i--;
      elems[2].textContent = i;
    } else if (i <= 4 && i != 1) {
      i--;
      elems[2].textContent = '';
      elems[2].classList.add("active");
      elems[3].classList.remove("active");
      console.log('i = ' + i);
      if (i === -3) {
        clear();
          }
    } else if (i = 1 && j != 1) {
      j--;
      elems[1].classList.remove("active");
      elems[2].classList.remove("active");
      elems[2].classList.add("greenText");
      elems[2].textContent = j;
      elems[3].classList.add("active");
      console.log('j = ' + j);
    }
  }, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял у вас выполнение останавливается вызовом функции `clear`.

Не убирайте в этой функции таймер, а просто инициализируйте нужные переменные  первоначальным значением.